# Debugging DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE driver BSOD on Sony Vaio Z12 and Win 8.1

Tags: drivers, bsod, sony-vaio, windbg

I need a bit of help tracking down which driver is causing issues with suspend/hibernate on my laptop.

I have a 3.5 year old Vaio VPCZ12 that doesn't have official support for Win 8, although I have successfully installed Win 8 on it several times now using Win 7 drivers.

I just reformatted and installed Win 8.1. After installing all the drivers along with VMware, Virtual Box and NetLimiter I'm seeing a problem where the system can't enter suspend or hibernate.

Initially I got a BSOD DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE. I ran the minidump of that through windbg and it showed that the faulting module was nlndis.sys, which is a driver used by NetLimiter.

I uninstalled NetLimiter and I still can't get the system to enter suspend or hibernate, but the problem is that now I get a hang instead of a BSOD. Basically, the PC just sits there with a blank screen, fan running at 100% and that's it... So, I don't get a dump to debug.

In the meantime I found a memory.dmp file, but I'm not certain if this was created before or after I uninstalled NetLimiter. It had the following info:

```
DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5215f837

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff80000092000 pci

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17029 (debuggers(dbg).140219-1702) amd64fre

DPC_STACK_BASE:  FFFFF80326EFEFB0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff803`26ef7a68 fffff803`256798d2 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 ffffe000`0170e060 fffff803`26ef7aa0 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff803`26ef7a70 fffff803`256797f2 : ffffe000`03a54290 00000000`00000008 00000000`00000002 fffff803`25503dbc : nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck+0xde
fffff803`26ef7ad0 fffff803`255026e2 : 00000000`00000000 fffff803`26ef7c20 ffffe000`03a542c8 ffffe000`02762c10 : nt!PopIrpWatchdog+0x32
fffff803`26ef7b20 fffff803`255d2bea : fffff803`25770180 fffff803`25770180 fffff803`257c8a80 ffffe000`045a7080 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x6b2
fffff803`26ef7da0 00000000`00000000 : fffff803`26ef8000 fffff803`26ef2000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.3.9600.16384

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_Netwsw00_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_Netwsw00_IMAGE_pci.sys

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_power_down_netwsw00_image_pci.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {42750416-ec89-5a17-1bbd-443b00aa8536}

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Can anyone suggest what my next course of action should be to trace this problem?

**Update #1:**

So, thanks to @magicandre1981 I've tracked the problem down to both my network drivers:

1. Intel 82577LC Gigabit Ethernet
2. Intel 6200 AGN Wireless

If I disable both of these, the laptop can enter suspend/hibernate. If either of these is enabled the suspend hangs (and I don't get a BSOD).

For the 6200AGN I've tried both the latest Intel driver as well as the old Win 7 driver from Sony and both seem to exhibit the same problem. For the 82577C for some reason the Intel driver does not recognize the NIC and refuses to install so I disabled the device and focuse on testing the with other WiFi NIC.

**So...** Since I don't get a BSOD I still don't really have any idea what the problem might be. Can anyone suggest how to trace what might be hanging the suspend process?

Are there any power management features on network cards in general that could cause this kind of problem? Can I disable these?

Would really appreciate any advice you guys can give. I'm in the middle of a big project and this is really becoming a big issue for me.

**Update #2:**

Well I tried downloading the drivers as per the advice below and that didn't resolve anything.

Aside from these issues with the network cards I also started seeing problems with random explorer crashes and significant slowdowns after an hour or two of working in Adobe Illustrator, which wouldn't resolve without a restart.

In the end, I simply too busy to worry about this so in the end I gave up and I've reinstalled Win 7. It's ugly, but at least it works. :)

Thanks to everyone for the help.

Comment: What's the current BIOS version? Could you specify the hardware IDs for both network cards?

Comment: upload the dmp file so that I can see which card it was which caused the BSOD.

Comment: @and31415: Bios version is: INSYDE R3030C3, 7/30/2010
The bios has a custom patch applied to enable manual switching of the hybrid graphics system.
The hardware ids for the NICs are:
82577LC NIC: PCI\VEN_8086DEV_10EB&SUBSYS_905A104D&REV_05
6200AGN NIC: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_422C&SUBSYS_13018086&REV_35

Comment: @magicandre1981: Sorry, don't feel comfortable sharing the memory dmp for security reasons. Can you tell me what I should look for?

Comment: upload the minidump. it doesn't contain personal data.

Comment: @AndyAtTheWebists What's the current driver version for each card? You can get the latest generic drivers here: [Ethernet](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Ethernet+Components&ProductLine=Ethernet+Controllers&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+82577+Gigabit+Ethernet+PHY); [Wi-Fi](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wtech/proset-ws/sb/CS-034041.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The cause is the driver Netwsw00.sys which is a Intel WIFI driver. Download and install the [latest driver from Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&keyword=ProSet%20Wireless) to fix it.